# How to fix 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option' in Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Environment:**

Python 3.10

selenium==4.3.0

Windows 10

**Problem**

I am trying to make a selenium script with Chrome.

```
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=" + chrome_profile_path)
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-session-crashed-bubble")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

I execute the code from my Windows terminal. It creates this issue:

```
chrome_profile_path : C:\Users\gauth\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
You don't have Chrome browser installed on your computer or we di'nt find your profile folder! : 'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'
```

So in the same terminal, I executed python and typed these lines below in order to reproduce the issue:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

And I didn't get any issue.

So why do I get the issue when I execute my script and not when I execute line by line in Python terminal?

Here is the full code:

```
def ChromeDriverWithProfile():
    """
    This function will return the chrome driver with the Chrome profile loaded
    """

    try:
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            chrome_profile_path = os.environ['HOME'] + "/.config/google-chrome"
            chrome_profile_path = os.path.expandvars(chrome_profile_path)
        elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
            if not os.environ['HOME'] or os.environ['HOME'] == "":
                HOME_DIR = os.path.expanduser("~")
            else:
                HOME_DIR = os.environ['HOME']
            chrome_profile_path = HOME_DIR + "/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default"
            chrome_profile_path = os.path.expandvars(chrome_profile_path)
        else:
            chrome_profile_path = r"%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data"
            chrome_profile_path = os.path.expandvars(chrome_profile_path)

        print(f"chrome_profile_path : {chrome_profile_path}")
        chrome_options = Options()

        chrome_options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=" + chrome_profile_path)
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-session-crashed-bubble")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"]) # !!!! THE ISSUE COME HERE AT THIS LINE !!!!
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

        # overcome limited resource problems
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        # Bypass OS security model
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        # We need to remove the bubble popup 'Restore pages' of Chrome:
        # https://dev.to/cuongld2/get-rid-of-chrome-restore-bubble-popup-when-automate-gui-test-using-selenium-3pmh
        if platform.system() == 'Linux':
            preference_file = chrome_profile_path + "/Default/Preferences"
        elif platform.system() == 'Darwin':
            preference_file = chrome_profile_path
        else:
            preference_file = chrome_profile_path + "\\Default\\Preferences"
        string_to_be_change = '"exit_type":"Crashed"'
        new_string = '"exit_type": "none"'
        # read input file
        fin = open(preference_file, "rt")
        # read file contents to string
        data = fin.read()
        # replace all occurrences of the required string
        data = data.replace(string_to_be_change, new_string)
        # close the input file
        fin.close()
        # open the input file in write mode
        fin = open(preference_file, "wt")
        # overrite the input file with the resulting data
        fin.write(data)
        # close the file
        fin.close()

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
        return driver
    except Exception as ex:
        print(
            f"You don't have Chrome browser installed on your computer or we di'nt find your profile folder! : {ex}")
        return None


driver = ChromeDriverWithProfile()
```

I searched for this issue "'Options' object has no attribute 'add_experimental_option'" on the web. There isn't anything. Obviously, I am the only one on earth who has this issue. :-(

Can you help me, please?

Comment: I'm too having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

use ChromeOptions() like this

option = ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation'])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).